# how can an inverse correlation matrix have <1 in diagonals. the correlations x1, x2 are about 0.5

Tags: matrix-inverse

The inverse correlation matrix was calculated with the minverse function. The results show that in the diagonal the values are less than 1. how is this possible? the x1,x2 independent variables are correlated at about 0.5

Comment: That is improbable, as you would expect the determinant and diagonal terms of the inverse matrix to be greater than $1$.  For example $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & \frac12\\ \frac12 & 1 \end{pmatrix}^{-1} 
= \begin{pmatrix} \frac43  & -\frac23\\ -\frac23 & \frac43 \end{pmatrix}$.  What was your correlation matrix?

Comment: Where is the function `minverse`?  Language, package?  Also show us your correlation matrix,  and see  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/120459/diagonal-elements-of-the-inverted-correlation-matrix

Comment: henry thank you for the reply. hopefully you can get the below information it is column 
                ozone            solar           wind          temp
ozone 1.0000000 0.5996416 0.2000837 -0.2395500
solar 0.5996416 1.0000000 0.0545718 -0.6240431
wind 0.2000837 0.0545718 1.0000000 -0.9028647
temp 0.2395500 -0.6240431 -0.9028647 1.0000000